# subview UIButton click event not working from ViewController swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My Custom `EmptyUIView`. I want to call `UIView` uiBtnExplore from `UIViewController`.

```
class EmptyView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var uiBtnExplore: UIButton!

    class func createEmptyView() -> EmptyView {
        let myEmptyNib = UINib(nibName: "EmptyView", bundle: nil)
        return myEmptyNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! EmptyView
    }
}
```

**My UIViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class PlaylistViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {
    var itemInfo: IndicatorInfo = "PLAYLISTS"
    var emptyView:EmptyView!

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        emptyView = EmptyView.createEmptyView()
        self.emptyView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                        y: view.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.view.addSubview(emptyView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(testButton)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        self.emptyView.uiBtnExplore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button Clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a crash? Because the selector doesn't seems right and I think it should crash with a "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error message. But doing `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` might also causes an issue.

Comment: No, my view show correctly but after button click nothing happened

Comment: @Tariqul Try to debug with the 3D view. Make sure this button don't behind or stuck from other views

Comment: check hierarchy of views in document Outline.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I got issue. when make empty view size freedom and give size then button click not working but when i give inferred then it works but i can't understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have disabled userInteraction  with your view, When you disable user interaction it disabled interaction with all of its subviews change below line

```
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

**With**

```
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, I try this but still not working

Comment: self.emptyView.uiBtnExplore.uiBtnExplore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
try this one for selector, also keep userInteraction enabled

Comment: if this does not  work then also check the location for test button it  may be overlapping  uiBtnExplore, Or may uiBtnExplore frame causing the issue .

Comment: I just add only empty view now